# Need help turning subqueries into JOIN's

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Can anyone help me turn this subquery-based query into JOIN's?

```
SELECT DISTINCT brm_products_assets_id,
(select brm_products_assets_value from brm_products_assets_values where brm_products_assets_id=a.brm_products_assets_id and brm_products_assets_def_id=1) as prod_asset_name,
(select brm_products_assets_value from brm_products_assets_values where brm_products_assets_id=a.brm_products_assets_id and brm_products_assets_def_id=3) as prod_asset_desc,
(select brm_products_assets_value from brm_products_assets_values where brm_products_assets_id=a.brm_products_assets_id and brm_products_assets_def_id=2) as prod_asset_type,
ifnull((select brm_products_assets_value from brm_products_assets_values where brm_products_assets_id=a.brm_products_assets_id and brm_products_assets_def_id=5),'') as file_order 
from brm_products_assets a where last_mnt_option!='d';
```

This query currently takes over 20 seconds to execute. I tried an index on brm_products_assets_value but it didn't help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to do conditional aggregation, not separate queries:

```
SELECT brm_products_assets_id,
       max(case when brm_products_assets_def_id = 1 then brm_products_assets_value
           end) as prod_asset_name,
       max(case when brm_products_assets_def_id = 2 then brm_products_assets_value
           end) as prod_asset_desc,
       max(case when brm_products_assets_def_id = 3 then brm_products_assets_value
           end) as prod_asset_type,
       max(case when brm_products_assets_def_id = 5 then brm_products_assets_value else ''
           end) as file_order
from brm_products_assets a join
     brm_products_assets_values b
     on b.brm_products_assets_id = a.brm_products_assets_id
where last_mnt_option <> 'd'
group by a.brm_products_assets_id;
```